# Create a member variable using map cpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to call a function using a `std::map` key value pair. I found this stackoverflow article [Calling a function depending on a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435732/calling-a-function-depending-on-a-variable/39435937) but the solution

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> le_mapo;
```

does not work and results in a error something like "error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand" using it as so

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> le_mapo;
le_mapo["ftp"] = &ftp(); // ftp function is in the same class, this function is the constructor
```

I am trying to call a function in the same class with this method and it results in a lvalue error any idea what to do

I have also tried using at the top

```
#define BE_EVIL(map, function, x) map[ #x ] = & function ## x
```

NOTE: i have all the proper includes such as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
```

here is a Reproducible Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>


class stackoverflow
{
    private:
        void ftp();
    
    public:
        stackoverflow();
};

void ftp()
{
    std::cout << "Minimal reproduction" << std::endl;
}

stackoverflow::stackoverflow()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> le_mapo;
    le_mapo["ftp"] = &ftp();
}
```

Comment: `&ftp()` is calling the function and then applying the adress of operator. `&ftp` is the function pointer. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: the answer in the Q&A you link is correct and it does work that way. You just didnt do what the answer suggests

Comment: however, if `ftp` is a member function then you might encounter other problems, thats why we need a [mcve] to help you

Comment: Please see the updated answer @463035818_is_not_a_number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `ftp` is a member function, you are going to have to use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) here (well, you could use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), but lambdas have largely superseded that these days).

So you want:

```
le_mapo["ftp"] = [this](){ ftp(); };
```

This "captures" `this`, thus enabling you to call `ftp()` on the correct object.

`&ftp()` doesn't work for a number of reasons:

- appending `()` means that you are attempting to call the function (and then taking the address of whatever it returns), rather than taking the address of `ftp` directly.
- the syntax for taking the address of a member function is `&stackoverflow::ftp`, and not just `&ftp`.
- you are not passing `this` anywhere, so the caller won't have an object to call `ftp` on.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
le_mapo["ftp"] = &ftp();
```

is wrong because `ftp()` is calling the function and only then the address-of operator is applied. Though you cannot take the adress of `void`. The function pointer is `&stackoverflow::ftp`.

You need an object to call a member function. `std::function` has some magic to turn a member function into a callable that takes the object as parameter, hence this works:

```
stackoverflow::stackoverflow()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(stackoverflow&)>> le_mapo;
    le_mapo["ftp"] = &stackoverflow::ftp;
}
```

When calling the functions in the map you must pass a reference to an object of type `stackoverflow` that will be used to call the member function.

Alternatively you can wrap the object together with the member function in a lambda, as shown in the ohter answer.

---

PS: I suppose there is a typo in your code, because this:

```
void ftp()
{
    std::cout << "Minimal reproduction" << std::endl;
}
```

is a free function completely unrelated to `stackoverflow::ftp`. You don't need a lambda (other answer) or a `std::function` with an additional paramter when `ftp` is a free function. For free functions the answer in the Q&A you link is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the more indepth explanation, is lambda better practice or this?

Comment: @JonathanColetti it depends what you want. The lambda in the other answer can only be used as long as `this` is still alive. The `std::function<void(stackoverflow&)>` does not depend on the object that created it but can be called with other objects. On the other hand, it must get an object passed which can be a minus when you call it with the same object only anyhow

Comment: Interesting bit about that... Technically no. `void ftp()` declares (and goes on to define) a free function named `ftp` which is completely different from the `stackoverflow::ftp` that is declared in the `stackoverflow` class. No lambda required, but if you really wanted to use  `stackoverflow::ftp`  you would need to bundle `this` into something to be able to invoke `stackoverflow::ftp` on `this`. That or make `stackoverflow::ftp` `static`.

Comment: @JonathanColetti oh right. Is that a typo in the question? Do yuo really want to have two different `ftp` functions?